# How to have certain products show for only certain users (Not roles)

Tags: plugins, user-roles

I am not a coder so this has been a difficult journey for me.

I run a giftware wholesale company and am trying to have it so different retailers can have their own custom product show up in the category I've made called "Your custom products". So far I've attempted to use the plugin "Members" so you can assign multiple roles to a user. Hence I'd make a user a "wholesale customer" so they can see all the regular products, and then also assign them to "_____ custom Profile" as well. That way I was restricting their role to certain products from the editing page, but for some reason along the way the roles from "Members" and "Wholesale Suite" don't recognize the roles made from one another.

So for example, if I make a role in wholesale suite, it will not show up when I go to edit the user to assign multi-roles and pic their custom roles. It WILL show up if I create the role on the "Members" plugin, but then will not show up when i'm on the editing product page where I go to restrict the content to the specific role I want to be able to see it.

I hope this makes sense to anyone reading, it's been super frustrating as a large part of our business is being able to offer custom wholesale products.

please help.

Comment: Is this for an ecommerce platform, or only product info? If it’s eCommerce, this question belongs elsewhere, not in WordPress Development.